# How to aggregate data from prometheus jmx_exporter and simpleclient into a single HTTP endpoint

Tags: java, jmx-exporter, prometheus-java

I have a application which uses jmx_exporter to expose metrics to prometheus, now i want to use simpleclient to expose application specific custom metrics. Both of these are exposing a new http server to expose metrics with identical format which results in exposing metrics in 2 endpoints.
I want to combine result of both and expose in one single endpoint.
As i check jmx_exporter is also using **simpleclient** in its dependencies but not able to find way to combine both responses

I'm able to expose custom metrics with primitive data types in jmx_exporter through creating a Mbean but exposing Gauge, Counter etc. types metrics through Mbean is not working(not visible in end-point response).

**Note:** i have to use simpleclient to expose custom metrics because no support of labels in jmx_exporter